# Letters are arranged in boxes

Tags: permutations

[image]

Ways =(selecting one box from upper and lower rows)(selecting four boxes out of remaining)(number of ways arranging six letters in these boxes)

$$={3\choose 1}{3\choose 1}{6 \choose 4}\cdot6!$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[\begin{align}
  & There\text{ are 3 cases to be considered : }\left( 1,1,1,3 \right)\text{ ,}\left( 2,1,1,2 \right)\text{ }and\text{ }\left( 3,1,1,1 \right) \\ 
 & \underline{case\text{ 1}}\text{ :  }top\text{ }row\text{ }1:6C1*3 \\ 
 & \text{            }second\text{ }row\text{ }1:5C1 \\ 
 & ~\text{               }third\text{ }row\text{ }1:\text{ }4C1 \\ 
 & ~\text{               }fourth\text{ }row\text{ }3\text{ : }3C3*3! \\ 
 & Soln~\text{ :    }6C1*3*5C1*4C1*\text{ }3C3*3!=2160 \\ 
 & \text{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------} \\ 
 & \underline{case\text{ 2}}\text{ :  }top\text{ }row\text{ }1:6C2*3P2 \\ 
 & \text{            }second\text{ }row\text{ }1:4C1 \\ 
 & ~\text{               }third\text{ }row\text{ }1:\text{ }3C1 \\ 
 & ~\text{               }fourth\text{ }row\text{ }3\text{ : }3C3*3P2 \\ 
 & Soln~\text{ :    }6C2*3P2*4C1*3C1*3C3*3P2=6480 \\ 
 & ------------------------------------------ \\ 
 & \underline{case\text{ 3}}\text{ :  }top\text{ }row\text{ }1:6C3*3! \\ 
 & \text{            }second\text{ }row\text{ }1:3C1 \\ 
 & ~\text{               }third\text{ }row\text{ }1:\text{ }2C1 \\ 
 & ~\text{               }fourth\text{ }row\text{ }3\text{ : }1C1*3 \\ 
 & Soln~\text{ :   }6C3*3!*3C1*2C1*\text{ }1C1*3=2160 \\ 
 & ------------------------ \\ 
 & Total\text{ }Soln=case1+\text{ }case2+case3=2160+4680+2160=10800 \\ 
\end{align}]

Answer (score 1):

No, that is both over counting *and* does not ensure that all rows have at least one box selected.

You need to select, the boxes in the 2 middle rows and either:

- 1 from 3 in the top row *and* all 3 in the bottom row, xor
- all 3 in the top row *and* 1 from 3 in the bottom row, xor
- 2 from 3 in the top row *and* 2 from 3 in the bottom row

Then when you have selected the boxes, arrange the 6 letters within them.

Count the ways.

> $10800$

Comment: How it is over counting . I have ensured that each row gets atleast one box by $(^3_1)(^3_1)$

Comment: You have selected one box each in the top and bottom rows, then any four of the six remaining boxes, which *does not* ensure either of the middle rows are selected. Further, since order of selecting the box does not matter you are over counting cases such as selecting two of the top row, et cetera.  @user123733